# What is the difference between lightgbm.LGBMModel and lightgbm.LGBMClassifier?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Python-API.html

I have compared both of them in the lightgbm documentation and could not figure out which one I would choose and why I would choose one over the other?

Answer (score 2):

Glancing at the source (available from your link), it appears that `LGBMModel` is the parent class for `LGBMClassifier` (and Ranker and Regressor).  You should probably stick with the Classifier; it enforces proper loss functions, adds an array of data classes, translates the model's score into class probabilities and from there into predicted classes, etc.